# In which countries did broadcasting rights for the World Cup sell for the most?

Tags: football, media, world-cup

In which countries did broadcasting rights for the World Cup sell for the most? If possible, let's include all media (TV, streaming internet, radio) and all languages (so in the U.S. this would include Univision buying the Spanish-language rights).

The thing that got me started thinking about this was the question of whether the rights are highly valuable in the U.S. Specifically, I was thinking:

1. Soccer (or "football", if you prefer) generally does not get a large television audience in the United States.
2. However, the World Cup may be an exception (it certainly is among the people I talk to).
3. Plus, the U.S.'s has a large population and, more importantly, the world's highest GDP. Presumably the value of advertisements is roughly proportional to the population, holding other factors constant.
4. Lastly, with the Cup being in Brazil this year the games are on at a reasonable time for most Americans.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might not be possible to determine definitively.

Often, the deals that FIFA negotiates for media rights cover multiple events and multiple years.  For example, in 2005, ABC/ESPN and Univision purchased the USA rights to all FIFA events from 2007-2014.  This included the 2010 and 2014 World Cups, the 2007 and 2011 Women's World Cups, and the 2009 and 2013 Confederations Cups, and includes all TV, Radio, Mobile, and Internet rights.  The English language portion of the contract was $100 million, and the Spanish language rights were $325 million.  At the time, this USA deal was called "the biggest TV deal in a single country in FIFA's history."  ([Source](http://www.soccertimes.com/worldcup/2005/nov02.htm))

[FIFA has a list (.pdf)](http://www.fifa.com/mm/document/affederation/tv/01/47/76/00/2014fifaworldcupbrazil%28tm%29mediarightslicenseelist140614%5fneutral.pdf) of all 2014 World Cup media licensees, worldwide, for TV, Radio, Mobile, and Internet, sorted by territory.